# Odoo-12 trigger function on "Enter" keypress in char field

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-12

I have a Char field in a form in Odoo-12. Is it possible to trigger
a method with the fields value as parameter when the Enter key is pressed without writing a Javascript widget for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write onchange method in it to trigger it and in that you can also get the values of that field.

Comment: That's easier. Thanks! I assumed @api.onchange would be triggered on any keypress...